# How to obtain info about really old bank account

Tags: bank-account

I recently bought a very old book in an antique book store. The book was printed before 1850 (I don’t want to reveal the exact year). I found on the internet that the same book sold for 10 times higher price and currently there doesn’t appear to be any copy available for sale, so the book is valuable on it’s own. The book is in English, but printed in France, I think (weird).

What’s interesting is that on one of last empty pages I found a number written by pen at the top of the page. The number resembles format of a bank account. It could also be an identification number used by some library where the book may have spent a few years. One of the numbers appears to be an identification number of a German bank that exists since 19th century. The account number (if it is account number) is 4 digit and based on some online search could such an account be opened before 1914. On another page I found 3 separate numbers with notes and each of these appear to be medical diagnose described by a code. It could have been written into the book later, perhaps by a student of medical school, or it could be password to that bank account (I know it’s unlikely, but one never knows...).

Is there a way of getting some info on this bank account, like through a notary? I know that banks are not going to reveal any info unless documentation related to bank account is presented, so they don’t even tell anyone if the bank account is still open. But if it’s anonymous account (not sure if this was possible back then) proper credential info, like password might unlock the access to the account.

Is it possible to find somehow if that account is still valid (and perhaps take over the account, obviously). If not, would it be possible to at least find rightful owner, so he or she could claim it. I definitely don’t like the idea to leave it to the bank or the state, if it really is existing account.
Any idea how to “grasp” this?

---

This book also has a different number painted on the cover - that definitely looks like some library identification. It's possible that some library was getting rid off old books (don't understand why they would do that in case if this book) or perhaps someone didn't return the book and perhaps whoever was going over inheritance found it and sold it to the antique book store. I'm thinking if I could find which library had this book originally, it may be possible to find in their records who gave them the book (perhaps someone donated it decades ago). This original owner of the book might be the rightful owner of the account (if it really is a bank account). Perhaps they don't even know about it, in that case it would be a nice surprise to find that it exists and they can claim it after all these years.

I could send 1 Euro to this account to see if the payment goes through or bounces back :-) .

Comment: *and perhaps take over the account, obviously* I hope you recognize that doing so would be theft.

Comment: Without extremely extraordinary circumstances, an account that has had no contact with an owner or authorized representative for a long time (some 10-20 years) will have been turned over to the state. The specifics on when and how to 'escheat' will depend on the jurisdiction where the account is held, but if the account is as old as you think, there is almost 0 chance that it is still viable.

Comment: @dwizum - I meant of course if it has no living owner, nobody inherited it, forgotten account, lost in history. These accounts sometimes had zero interest rate, so the balance may have stayed the same all these years and have no great value today.

Comment: @R.Hamilton that’s true, sometimes it’s 50 years. However records are never discarded, so balance may be turned over to the state, but if someone can reclaim it later, even after 100 years - as a result of inheritance or in case of anonymous account using password, the bank has to fulfill it’s obligation and the state would have to return the money. There haven’t been many cases like that, so it’s possible that state would be unwilling to return the money it already devoured (which would just indicate their attitude towards private property).

Comment: The fact that time has passed doesn't change the fact that property has a rightful owner. You can't claim it just because it's *old*. The concept of escheatment basically implies that property *always* has a rightful owner, and is held in custody until the rightful owner is able to prove their ownership claim. Finding numbers written in a book doesn't make you the owner of the account, unless you intend to commit fraud and impersonate the owner as a means of claiming it.

Comment: *it’s possible that state would be unwilling to return the money it already devoured (which would just indicate their attitude towards private property)* I think you're misunderstanding escheatment. The bank and/or the state is required to respect the true ownership of the property. It is held in custody, ownership doesn't transfer. No one can "devour" or even gain access to the funds.

Comment: @dwizum: Well, the government will use the funds for its own purposes.  They'll be listed on the books as belonging to the account's rightful owner, but they won't accrue interest.

Comment: The first paragraph of this question doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure that's technically accurate but I suppose the finer details could vary by jurisdiction. In my state in the US at least, the custodian isn't allowed to have any access or utility from the funds (i.e. can't invest it, spend it, or earn interest from it). I think the OP has indicated they are from Germany. As far as I know, in Germany, the originating bank is required to hold the property, and they are similarly not allowed any utility from it. But maybe someone with more familiarity with German banking can come along and let us know if that's accurate or not.

Comment: @dwizum: "When property is reported and delivered to the State of Texas, the **Comptroller places the property in the general revenue fund** and the owner may claim it anytime thereafter"  That doesn't mean they're taking ownership, but at least in Texas, the government puts the money to use (to the benefit of the government).  For example, they can delay issuing bonds to raise money, by borrowing unclaimed funds instead.

Comment: Good to know, and honestly that seems more practical. In either case though, the principle of ownership doesn't change though, right? At least in the context of this question.

Comment: Even if the number _is_ a bank account number (a fairly big "if", in my view) there's absolutely nothing about this story (other than wishful thinking) to suggest it's an "abandoned" account. It's far more likely to have been closed normally some-when in the last 170 years. Hell, the owner of account could have written the number in the book (so they didn't forget it) the day they went into their bank and asked them to close the account.

Answer (score 5):

You asked,

> Is it possible to find somehow if that account is still valid (and perhaps take over the account, obviously.)

I think we need to pause for a minute here and reflect. The fact that time has passed doesn't change the fact that property has a rightful owner. **You can't claim it just because it's old.** The concept of *escheatment* basically implies that apparently-abandoned property **always** has a rightful owner, and is held in custody until the rightful owner is able to prove their ownership claim. Finding numbers written in a book doesn't make you the owner of the account.

You've mentioned the concept of an anonymous account with a password. Let's suppose for a minute that this is the case - this account was created in the 1800's and you now have a password that will act as a magic passphrase to get you access to the account regardless of whether or not you can prove your identity as it's rightful owner via any other means. You need to ask yourself:

- How does any of that imply that you have a legal (or ethical) right to claim the account?
- How does any of that infer that the account doesn't actually have a currently-very-alive rightful owner?
- What will happen when that rightful owner reports the crime you've just committed?

You've also asked,

> If not, would it be possible to at least find rightful owner, so he or she could claim it

No, that's not possible for you as a private individual to do. Firstly, as far as you know, if this account does exist, it's rightful owner is already aware of it. But, more importantly, **A bank that allowed public access to records of account ownership would not be viable.** Such records would, at worst, make it really easy for criminals to commit fraud and other crimes. And at best, it would be a violation of privacy and would enable all sorts of annoyances - I'm sure you can imagine that there are certainly cases where it would be very troublesome if people knew the details of your own personal banking habits.

Comment: Of course banks don't allow access to records to the public. But knowledge of bank account itself and even the name of the owner shouldn't allow criminals to commit fraud (unless the bank has really bad security procedures). For example my bank account is known probably to thousands of people, because I put it on invoices and perhaps even somewhere on my website (so that people knew where to send money).
That's what bank accounts are for - telling people/companies where to send money.
Sure, you usually give it only to your business partners, but it's very common to publish account numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many "ifs" and "whens".

> The number resembles format of a bank account.

How do you deduct that from? Because it starts with `DE`?

> One of the numbers appears to be an identification number of a German bank that exists since 19th century.

You might mean a "Bankleitzahl", a German routing number?

Well, the German routing number system was established in 1970, so I don't think it is about an account that comes from the time when the book was printed.

The SEPA system was established only in the last 10 years, and an account identified by an IBAN probably has been in use in the last 10 years.

So long story short, even if it identifies an account, it is unlikely that you can lawfully do anything with or about it.